# Bitmap rotation loosing quality in Java

Tags: java, bitmap

I'm trying to rotate a Bitmap image, but the problem is that the image looses quality Everytime I rotate it, and finally it gets blur.

Here's my Java code

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix ();
    matrix.setRotation(angle);
    Bitmap newBtmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    return newBtmp;
}
```

And then I tried to change the`filter` to false, but I still get the same result.

Please how can I rotate a bitmap without loosing quality?

Comment: Does the blur also occur for 90° rotations, where bitmap width is exactly equal to image height?

Comment: Do you set bitmap to the returned newBtmp? That way it would degrade.